# Lake Baikal: Where to get general information about ferries and is the ferry Severobajkalsk - Khakusy still running, and when?

Tags: ferries, baikal

We want to make a trip to lake Baikal end of June/ beginning of July 2019. We are interested in nature and remote places, and also not staying on the lake all the time, also the mountains.

We are interested in the north-east, but we do not want to hike the whole F.A.C.T. (Frolikha Adventure Coastline Trail).

Based on information about the F.A.C.T. from around 2010 (http://www.baikalinfo.com/html/german_gbt_fact.xml.php) there is mentioned a ferry between Severobajkalsk and the sanatorial place of Khakusy (Хакусы). Is it still running, and how often and when?

What ferries in general are running along the lake, or where are possibilities to get transported by private persons for a reasonable price?

Are there still long distance ferries betweek Irkutsk, Olchon and Severobaikalsk? Are there East-west-crossings?

On the internet I only find information about transportation (and boats) in the Irkutsk reagion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the only ferry operator for Lake Baikal is VSRP, and their complete schedule is here:
https://vsrp.ru/en/passengers/timetable/

While both services used to operate, at time of writing, VSRP has no services to/from Severobaikalsk at the northern end of the lake or Tankhoy on the east coast. Olkhon is still served regularly.

As for private arrangements, perhaps a tour agency could arrange a chartered trip for you, but unless you have a large group the cost is unlikely to be "reasonable", since it would be 12+ hours one way from Irkutsk to Severobaikalsk and Baikal's notorious storms mean you wouldn't want to tackle this in a small boat.  Tankhoy is much closer and might be more feasible, but it's also reachable by train.

Comment: As far as I know the boat to Khakusy (Хакусы) is a private one to the hot spring resort.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the answer about the ferry company VSRP:

Severobaikalsk - Khakusy is served by a small boat whose timetable can be seen there: http://hakusy.com/transfer/ and also can be reserved there.